# Invoking caller activity from callee activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have many activities ( say activity **A**, **B**, **C**) calling a single activity ( say activity **D**) for a result (`startActivityForResult(..)`).

But want to do something according to the caller activity in the callee activity ( activity **D**) before the callee sets result and finishes.

The task I want to do *needs to use data variables of the calling activity*, so now I am planning to pass a callback class similar to this:

```
public interface myCallBack implements Seriabizable{

    public void myMethod();

}
```

from each caller to the callee on launching the activity;

```
intent.putExtra(CALL_BACK_OBJECT_KEY, new myCallBack(){

    @Override
    public void myMethod(){
        //code that uses instance variables of caller class
    }
});
```

of course the callback is seriabizable.

```
myCallback = getIntent().getSerializableExtra(CALL_BACK_OBJECT_KEY);
```

Now the callee activity ( activity **D**) will do the task like this:

```
myCallback.myMethod();
```

But is this the right way of doing it? Is it good to pass callback class across activities? What other options are available?

Or is there a way to call methods of the caller activity directly? In this case I will force the caller activities to implement `MyCallBack` interface.

---

**NB:**
The reason I dont want to pass the data needed from caller to callee is, the data needed by the task is completely different for each caller activity and also some time big. So I dont to mess the callee activity with those data variables.

Comment: no, you could pass Binder ... but generally communication between Activities makes no sens (other then passing Intents back and forth) ... Think in this way: there can only be one Activity running at the time

Comment: never used Binder I will read it but can you give the general picture?

Comment: heh, forget about Binder ... I mentioned about this as it is a nearest thing to interface what could be passed via parcerable(intent), it is rather for IPC and Service other android componet comunication ... **just use startActivityForResult** ...

Comment: But am already using `startActivityForResult`.

Comment: then why you need interface? ... do the stuff in onActivityResults(of the caller) based on results (returned from callee) ...

Comment: oh I got what you mean, but the callee has to execute the task before setting the result. The result also depends on the task if that makes sense?

Comment: about edit: so this "big" data are stored as caller activity variable? ... good luck ... now test this app with [Don't keep activites](http://selvin.pl/dka.png)

Comment: By big data I mean many member variables. Also yeah some of my activity contain database objects from a custom ORM.

Answer (score 0):

What you suggest may work. However it looks complicated and not a good practice.

If you just want to pass data accross activity, why don't you use `intent.putExtra` with the data you want to pass accross activities ?

If the data you want to pass are too large, or too complex, to be pass like that, maybe you should implement your application another way. You could for instance use a `Service`. You wil have a three services (one for each activity, or use case). These services will implement a common interface or herit from the same class. Your calling actvity (A, B or C) will start the appropriate service and the service will store the datas. When you start the activity D, this activity will bind with the service. Then she will be able to fully access all datas or objects from the service.

Comment: It makes sense but have to define a service per each activity?

Comment: It depends. If each activity do realy different task yes, otherwise no.